# How to debug phonegap on Windows

Tags: windows-7, cordova

Is there any way to Debug Phonegap Apps on a Windows 7 PC?
It takes quite a long time to upload this stuff to the Phone everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Ripple emulator plugin for Chrome. It allows you to simulate how your app would work on a multitude of devices. If you are using anything outside of the core cordova.js/phonegap.js (meaning plugins) I do not think it will work though. For basic testing it works great.